# Hibernate Annotation - 1 to 1 with no auto_increment

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations, persistence

How do I proceed in terms of Hibernate Annotation (JPA) when a table's primary key column is a foreign key to another table with no auto_increment (MySQL).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should work (not tested for exact syntax, but should be close):

```
@Id
private int id;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id", updatable = false, insertable = false)
private RelationEntity other;
```

You would need to manually set your 'id' field before you persist it, and can't remember if you can set the 'other' entity before the initial save, hibernate may complain if you do that. However, if your 'id' column is set then when you load the entity back out you should have the relationship loaded as well.

Comment: The first approach that came in mind was, before I persist the "id" field, I would retrieve the last persisted "id" from the other table via "max(a.id) from A a" hql + 1, and than, I set the "id" value through its Setter method. I'll try and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the other entity object around? Is it persisted before, after, or during the time you are saving this entity? It sounds like it would be easiest if you were doing this in a transaction then you could do: em.persist(other); other.getId(); and not worry about the max(a.id) thing

Comment: Both are saved at the same time (not at the same time, you know. Hibernate's engine takes care) because the entity that holds the FK has the other entity as its field (e.g. a.setB(b)) with appropriate Annotation "marks" (@OneToOne, @JoinColumn and @Cascade). Because of that Hibernate save() method is used once to persist the A Entity. Did I make my self clear?

Comment: I tried what I suggested and, since I set format_sql as true, what I see here is just the SQL "insert" statement for the Entity that holds the FK(A entity as mentioned above). Long story short... hasn't worked. Even using hql (max()...) to set the A id's field via setter before persists the object, hibernate throw MySQL exception warning the constraint fault (Cannot add or update child row:...). Should I persist B entity even if A entity has a B entity? Just to mention (although I think it has nothing to do with that), it's a JSF project .

Comment: Think I understand what you are saying, and not sure it will work with one call to persist, even with the cascade value set. To see if the mappings work try making to calls to persist (kind of a pain, but just for testing): em.perist(other); dependent.setId(other.id); em.persist(dependent);  Obviously best if you do this in a transaction, but it should at least prove the mappings are correct and hibernate can deal with it at this level, then move on to try and get it to happen automatically.